# export default <Class> exports double nested default

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, module, editorjs

*First I want to say that I know my title is not the best way to describe my issue, but at the same time I don't have a clear understanding of this technology to be able to express it in a better way.*

#### Some info

I am working on an rather big open source project where by using webpack you can bundle whole thing together in a single file.

The project is mostly written in Typescript.

#### Build Up

I have a script that contains and exports class `Dom()` this way:

```
export default class Dom {
    //stuff
}
```

In a different script I import this class as `$` and access it by `$.functionName()` with no compiler errors.

```
import $ from './dom';

export default class SelectionUtils {
    //stuff
}
```

#### The Problem

After the whole project has been compiled and bundled with webpack I deploy it and see that the instance of class `Dom` is being deployed in the form of `_dom.default.default` instead of `_dom.default`. Meaning I have no access to the class functions.

Object structure:

```
_dom
 |--default
 |  |--default: f Dom()
 |  |--__esModule: true
 |  |--_proto_: Object
 |--_proto_: Object
```

Any hint on why this happens would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried to make this post as clear as I could, but again, since I don't understand the nature of the problem it's been really hard for me to express it.

Comment: If typescript is generating that code, it's a serious bug but I doubt that is the case. It sounds like you have some kind of weird loader issue. make sure all of your dependencies are up-to-date

Comment: @AluanHaddad the thing is that previous builds were OK. Then I applied many changes to the code but didn't really mess with the structure itself. I just imported a class to multiple scripts. I spent hours trying to figure this out but it made no sense to me.

I found a solution eventually but I am sure that I could do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a variable inside the class I want to use my import.

something like this:

```
export default class SelectionUtils {
    
    public $ = require('./dom').default;
    //stuff
}
```

I know that this probably is not the best solution but it works for now.